# create unique values in each cells for a given range in excel or R

Tags: r, excel, vba

Apologies if the example is not formatted properly.

I have a data set with one sample per row, the data contain two columns with reference numbers of the start value and end value.

- cell A1 = Sample #1
- cell B1 = 101-263 (start value)
- cell C1 = 101-266 (end value)
- cell A2 = Sample #2
- cell B2 = 162-186 (start value)
- cell C2 = 162-187 (end value)

The range of values is a different length of each row of data, with a maximum range of 8 values. I need to fill in the values in the range, with each value in a cell along the row.

So for sample #1 above I need to create the cell values:  D1 = 101-264, and E1 = 101-265

While for sample #2 there will be no extra cells needed.

Is there a formula (using Vlookup and If perhaps?) that I can create and drag across all rows and over the 8 needed columns to fill in this data? (I don't mind if there are N/A in the shorter-range rows)

If there is an easier way using R also fine with me.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try in D1 copied across eight columns and then D1:K1 copied down to suit:

```
=IF(1*RIGHT($C1,3)>RIGHT($B1,3)+COLUMN()-3,LEFT($B1,4)&RIGHT($B1,3)+COLUMN()-3,"")
```

The condition ([IF](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)) checks whether or not to display a result (or 'blank' `""`, for neater presentation) depending on the result equalling or exceeding the upper limit specified in ColumnC.

There is some text manipulation ([RIGHT](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f) and [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)) to get at the part that is to be integer incremented or to add back the static part.

[COLUMN()](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/COLUMN-function-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b) returns the column number (A>1, B>2 etc) so is useful as a kind of stepping function. In D1 `COLUMN()-3` is **4**-3 or `1` so there `1` is added to the start of the range (shown on the right of B1). When copied across to ColumnE `COLUMN()-3` becomes **5**-3, so `2` is added to the start of the range.

Comment: This works great! I went through the formula and I understand what you've done. Thanks!  I notice that +column()-3 is set as -3 because its in column D which has column value of 4. However, if i later insert a column in front of this data then the results get shifted +1.. is there a way to avoid this? Of course, I can reset the value to fix it but can i set "-3" in a different way that it would update automatically? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

# Create input example
dat = data.frame(
  sample = c("Sample #1", "Sample #2"), 
  start = c("101-263", "162-186"), 
  end = c("101-266", "162-187"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# Extract 'start' and 'end' values
dat$num1 = dat$start %>% strsplit("-") %>% sapply("[", 1)
dat$start2 = dat$start %>% strsplit("-") %>% sapply("[", 2) %>% as.numeric
dat$end2 = dat$end %>% strsplit("-") %>% sapply("[", 2) %>% as.numeric
dat$start = NULL
dat$end = NULL

# For each row
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) {

  # Check if there is any need to add entries
  if((dat$end2[i] - dat$start2[i]) > 1) {

    # For each entry
    for(j in seq(dat$start2[i], dat$end2[i] -1)) {

      # Create entry
      new_entry = data.frame(
        sample = dat$sample[i],
        num1 = dat$num1[i],
        start2 = dat$start2[i],
        end2 = j,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )

      # Add to table
      dat = rbind(dat, new_entry)

    }

  }

}

# Calculate all values
dat$value = paste0(dat$num1, "-", dat$end2)
dat = dat[, c("sample", "value")]

# Create column labels
dat = ddply(
  dat,
  "sample",
  transform,
  var = paste0("col", rank(value))
)

# Reshape to required format
dat = dcast(dat, sample ~ var, value.var = "value")
```

Does what you asked on the provided example.

It transforms this table -

```
     sample   start     end
1 Sample #1 101-263 101-266
2 Sample #2 162-186 162-187
```

Into this one -

```
     sample    col1    col2    col3    col4
1 Sample #1 101-263 101-264 101-265 101-266
2 Sample #2 162-187    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

If there is a larger example for testing will be happy to do so :)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I think in this instance it looks easier to do it in Excel, but good to know how to do this in R!